# How to split command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have a poll command, it will gonna `&poll [pollEvent] [agreeStatement] [disagreeStatement]`

Here's my code

```
if (command === 'poll') {
        let pollMessage = args[0]
        let aggree = args[1];
        let disagree = args[2];
        const agreeEmoji = '<a:verified:753654287338569778>'
        const disagreeEmoji = '<:no:753654286134542447>'
        if (!pollMessage) return message.reply("What are you going to poll?")
        if (!aggree) return message.reply('Please insert the aggree statement')
        if (!disagree) return message.reply("Please insert the disagree statement")
        const pollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Poll!')
        .setColor('#00FF2A')
        .addFields(
            { name: pollMessage, value: `
            <a:verified:753654287338569778> ${aggree}
            
            <:no:753654286134542447> ${disagree}`}
        )
        
        message.delete();
        let msg = await message.channel.send(pollEmbed);
        await msg.react('753654287338569778')
        await msg.react('753654286134542447')
 
        
        const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.id === '753654287338569778' || reaction.emoji.id === '753654286134542447'

        const result = await msg.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 5000}).then((collected) => {
            if (msg.reactions.cache.get('753654287338569778').count-1 <= 0 || msg.reactions.cache.get('753654286134542447').count-1 <= 0) return message.channel.send("No one voted sorry this poll is aborted")
            let resutEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Voting Complete!')
            .setColor('#00FF2A')
            .addFields( 
                {name: pollMessage, value: `<a:verified:753654287338569778> ${aggree} => ${collected.get('753654287338569778').count-1}
                
                <:no:753654286134542447> ${disagree} => ${collected.get('753654286134542447').count-1}`}
            )
        msg.edit(resutEmbed)
        msg.reactions.removeAll()
        })
        


    }
```

But the problem is, when I said `&poll Should I go outside? Yes No` it will shown like, because I want to be like `&poll Should I go outside? Yes No` then the bot will add Yes and No as the agree and disagree statement and make `Should I go outside?` as poll event message, any ideas?

[image: This image]

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more context, like the arguments passed that you use in args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `Array Destructuring` and the `rest operator` **ES6s** features will come handy for your command.

You can "destructure" your `args` Array elements and give each one a variable name by doing the following:

```js
// where: let [word1, word2, ...rest] = args
// is the same as:

let [word1, word2, ...rest] = ['Should', 'I', 'go', 'outside', 'yes', 'no'];
```

By doing this you can start working with the command entries, no matter how long these would be. Here `rest` is also declared as a variable and contains the "rest" of the elements that weren't named:

```js
console.log( rest );
// will prompt •> ['go', 'outside', 'yes', 'no']
```

If you want to enable personalized responses per poll, your implementation could be upgraded to:

```js
let [...question, option_a, option_b] = args;
```

Which would be fine for this case, although I would advise against making the command's answer options personalized if you're just looking to implement a `yes / no` poll.

If in the future you would like to offer more than two answer choices, you could design the command to detect them after a special character like:

```
&poll What's the coolest pet: dog, cat, panda
```

(Special character being `:` here)
You may also want to consider performing an `Array.join()` method and `String.split()` to process your command entry as the `...rest` operation way would only work for single worded answer options: `sure / nah`, and errors would come out if you get an entry like:

```
&poll Should I go outside?: sure thing nah
```

as `option_a` will contain `thing` / and `option_b` contain `nah`